# In choosing between MD-PhD and PhD, how should I factor in the expected age at which I'll start my career as a professor?

Tags: career-path, degree, medicine, age

My ideal career is to be lead a lab at a university as a professor.

If I completed a residency and fellowship after an MD-PhD, which I think I'd love because of the 80/20 split that fits my interests, I'd be in my mid to late 30s by the time I was ready to start an independent career, as opposed to a Ph.D., which I'd complete, with fellowship, around age 30.

I've heard the adage about scientists who don't contribute their biggest success before 30, and I'm concerned that close to 40 is far too late to start as an assistant professor.

Would I be better off going into a Ph.D.?

Comment: Which country is this? This is somewhat of relevance.

Comment: The average age of obtaining a PhD is past 30 in the US.

Comment: This is already generally addressed in [Are old (>35) faculty candidates discriminated against all over the world](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23613/are-old-35-faculty-candidates-discriminated-against-all-over-the-world) and [Am I likely to be perceived as less successful if I start as an assistant professor at age 40?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/28610/11365). The only potential difference in your situation is that you can choose between two doctoral degrees with different average completion times, which is why I've edited the post to highlight that difference.

Comment: I'm in the USA. How old is the data on that average? Most PhD students I know are much younger.

Comment: 2014, released every few years by the NSF.

Comment: Okay, thank you ff524. I searched, but must have missed those.

Comment: Not only US. It is somewhat rare to see phds with less than 30.... then you add some postdoc years...

Comment: @AnnaLippincott: note that the combination MD + PhD is pretty common in Medicine, so your case doesn't even compare to, for example, a biologist.

Comment: @AnnaLippincott the >30 number is for when they *obtain* their PhD not when they start it. More importantly, you might want to look at placement rates for the two programs into positions you would like and talk to faculty to understand these things better.

Answer (score 3):

According to the NSF's [report](http://www.nsf.gov/statistics/2016/nsf16300/start.cfm), the median age of a PhD recipient is 31.6 years old. That means you'll only be a little older than a typical graduate.

This age shouldn't be shocking considering in the US it often takes 10 or more years of college to obtain a PhD, so that means that most people will be late 20s or early 30s if they never went to industry or didn't graduate early.