# Ageism in Tenure-track applications

Tags: job-search, cv, job, tenure-track, age

I am applying tenure-track positions now, however I am about 10 years older than the average applicant (I worked many years in industry before PhD).

I talked to 2 experienced people whom I trust. Both said  ageism is an unfortunate reality of recruitment (especially in my technical field). One of them even told me it is OK to prepare a CV that doesn't reveal age. Although I don't know how that is possible since CV contains my B.Sc. degree date.

If two applications are about same then being 10 years young might be a plus. I am OK with that, but is that all? How strong is ageism in tenure-track recruitment process ? especially in technical fields such as physics, engineering, math, statistics etc...
Should I hide my B.Sc. degree date ? Doesn't it look weird ?

I wonder what people with TT committee experiences think about it. 
thanks.

Comment: If moving overseas is a possibility, that might help. Countries like Australia that do not have such strong tenure also tend to advertise positions at a wider range of levels (from entry-level right through to very senior professors) and are flexible about age. Your Industry experience is also going to be a bonus in some areas, so highlight it.

Comment: Trying to hide your age is pointless, because at some point, you'll get an in person interview and your age will show (unless you do look much younger). And agreeing with Significance, years of industry experience are an asset.

Comment: You may be interested in [this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23613/are-old-35-faculty-candidates-discriminated-against-all-over-the-world). Also see [my answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/28704/11192) to that question, which also touches on some of the things that I encountered as an older candidate (in the US, in an engineering field).

Answer (score 4):

The aspect of ageism and whether it plays a positive or negative role differs from one institution to another.

> *I  worked many years in industry before PhD*

The effect this would have on your application largely depends on what type of work are you associated with in the industry -- how well it attributes your tenure track position.

> *Should I hide my B.Sc. degree date?*

Frankly, I don't think this is a good idea. It is not professional and is not recommended for a CV. In fact, it might have the opposite effect of drawing attention to the information you wish to conceal.