# Age restrictions for teaching in united states

Tags: united-states, age

I am asking this question in a **general sense** (in the majority sense) and is not particular to any institute or topic.

Is there any upper age limit to join as an assistant professor in the US?

If a person completes her post-doc by the age of n, with no prior teaching experience. Is she eligible for assistant-professorship for 60 >= n >= 35?

Comment: Please read [JeffE's answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/23632/546) for the above linked question.

Answer (score 3):

**Defining limits violates age discrimination laws, which is why there are no age limits.**